# How to make a loop in python three that stops when you input the correct word/number

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am making a text based adventure game in python 3 and I was wondering what the simplest loop is. Using the code I have, it continues to print `"whats the number"` even when you put the correct number, also giving `9` as input doesnt work. It also doesn't work when I give `("8","9")`. Here is my code :

```
print("whats the number?")
required_number = ("8" or "9")

while True:
    number = input()
    if number == required_number:
        print ("GOT IT")
    else: print ("Wrong number try again")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
print("whats the number?")
required_number = [8,9]
while True:
    number = int(input())
    if number in required_number :
        print('GOT IT')
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong number try again')
```

Sample output in shell :

```
whats the number?
5
Wrong number try again
2
Wrong number try again
4
Wrong number try again
8
GOT IT
```

Answer (score 1):

print("whats the number?")

required_number = [8,9]

while True:
    number = input()

```
if number in required_number:

    print ("GOT IT")
    break

else:
    print ("Wrong number try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for in place of `==` is `in` since `required_number` is a tuple you're looking to see if the input is `in` `required_number`. Also the correct syntax for the tuple would be using a comma not `or`.

I also would make `required_number` plural to be a more accurate description of what it holds, and you probably want to use integers and not strings.

```
required_numbers = (8, 9)

while True:
    number = int(input("whats the number?"))
    if number in required_numbers:
        print("GOT IT")
        break #Stop asking
    else:
        print ("Wrong number try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `input` treats it as a `str` in **Python 3.x**
2. Preferably use a `list` for the required numbers
3. Using `in` to check for the number in the `required_numbers`
4. Put it in a try block to catch value error exceptions.

Hence:

```
required_number = [8,9]  # a list of integer types

while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("whats the number? "))   # Using `int` to convert the `str`
        if number in required_number:
            print ("GOT IT")
            break   # break out when the number is found
        else:
            print ("Wrong number try again")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input, Please enter an integer only.")
```

> Note: `==` determines if the values are `equal`, while `in` operator iterates over the list of elements and returns  `True` or `False`.

**OUTPUT**:

```
whats the number? g
Invalid Input, Please enter an integer only.
whats the number? abc
Invalid Input, Please enter an integer only.
whats the number? 3
Wrong number try again
whats the number? 9
GOT IT
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `required_number` or the input will accommodate a `string`, then you can use this:

```
required_number = [8,9]
required_number = str(required_number)
number = None

while True:
    number = input("Write a number: ")
    if number in required_number:
        print ("GOT IT")
    else: 
        print ("Wrong number try again")
```

Output:

```
Write a number: 3
Wrong number try again
Write a number: 8
GOT IT
Write a number: Hi
Wrong number try again
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Method**

```
print('Enter a Number:')
required_number = ['8','9']

while True:
number = input()
if number in required_number:
    print ("GOT IT")
    break
else:
    print ("Wrong number try again")
```